# Get count by where in with distinct sql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I made a query like this:

```
SELECT mit_rel, status, updatedate
FROM carts
WHERE mit_rel::integer in (60855, 60763, 60607)
```

The result is:

| mit_rel | status | updatedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60607 | 20 | 2023-03-09 11:08:54 |
| 60607 | 20 | 2023-03-15 10:15:31 |
| 60763 | 31 | 2023-03-17 16:26:01 |
| 60607 | 31 | 2023-03-17 10:13:34 |
| 60607 | 5 | 2023-03-15 14:39:41 |
| 60763 | 31 | 2023-03-17 14:50:46 |
| 60855 | 99 | 2023-04-21 17:37:17 |

I want to get **count(mit_rel)** and get the **latest status by updatedate**.

| mit_rel | status | updatedate | countr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60607 | 31 | 2023-03-17 10:13:34 | 4 |
| 60763 | 31 | 2023-03-17 16:26:01 | 2 |
| 60855 | 99 | 2023-04-21 17:37:17 | 1 |

Comment: Do already you know how to select an aggregation per group? E.g., the maximum updatedate per mit_rel? Or the number of rows per mit_rel? Then you'd be half-way there.

Comment: It's MySql. I know but the query I made is not working properly.

Comment: If you tried an aggreation query, but got wrong results, it may be you are running MySQL in cheat mode. In MySQL make sure you have `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to get the maximum date and the number of entries per mit_rel. Then join the table again to get the date's status.

```
SELECT
  c.mit_rel,
  c.status,
  c.updatedate,
  agg.number_of_carts
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    mit_rel,
    MAX(updatedate) AS max_updatedate,
    COUNT(*) AS number_of_carts
  FROM carts
  WHERE mit_rel in (60855, 60763, 60607)
  GROUP BY mit_rel
) agg
JOIN carts c ON c.mit_rel = agg.mit_rel AND c.updatedate = agg.max_updatedate
ORDER BY c.mit_rel;
```

Here is the same with window functions. We read the table just once, aggregate over the selected data and then pick the rows we want.

```
SELECT
  mit_rel,
  status,
  updatedate,
  number_of_carts
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    mit_rel,
    updatedate,
    status
    MAX(updatedate) OVER (PARTITION BY mit_rel) AS max_updatedate,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mit_rel) AS number_of_carts
  FROM carts
  WHERE mit_rel in (60855, 60763, 60607)
) agg
WHERE updatedate = max_updatedate
ORDER BY mit_rel;
```